# export image slices of model for resin printing

Tags: layers

How can I export individual images of a model for daylight resin printing.
Basically slicing the model into layer images.
The idea is to use Arduino to display each image on a LCD for a few seconds to cure each layer of the resin before moving up for the next layer.

Comment: What's wrong with a standard slicer like ChituBox? It can export in many formats including B/W jpg.

Comment: Thanks Benus, I got Chitubox and still in process of installing it on linux. Could be that I'll have upgrade. I found slic3r but it just doesn't what to open. So, still in progress

Comment: Also take in consideration, I'm running 32 bit